# Stack View in a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I am trying to implement a stack view inside a table view cell programmatically and add labels and buttons to it like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let dict = self.char[indexPath.row]
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    cell.addSubview(stackView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    let bornLabel = UILabel()
    bornLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
    let bornLabelValue = UILabel()
    bornLabelValue.textColor = UIColor.blue
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(bornLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(bornLabelValue)
    for (key, value) in dict {
        bornLabel.text = key
        bornLabelValue.text = value
        if key == "Height" {
            let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
            button.setTitle("English", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
         stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

The problem is that every time `tableView.reloadData()` is called, another cell is added on top of the existing one with different values for each label depending on the data given to the tableView. Or it might not generate another cell every time but just add another stackview. I'm not sure. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting a "**reusable cell**", that means it'll be an empty cell the first few times, and then it'll be a cell where you already added a `UIStackView`.

You should make a new prototype cell, either via the `Storyboard` or a new `XIB` file, add the `UIStackView` in it, and then only configure that stackView in your `cellForRowAt indexPath:` implementation.

Or you could technically set a tag in the stackView, and then check the cell for that tag… but please don't do this.

Comment: Your answer led me to the right place, thanks. I solved it by indeed using a prototype cell, adding a stackview to it and configuring that stackview in `cellForRowAt indexPath:`.  I had tried this before and instantiated my labels and buttons also in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` and not in my custom cell class, which now works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: how can i configure the stack view would you eloborate?

Comment: See lines 5 through 9 of the OP's original example. If you need more help, you should consider asking a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the stackView in the **cell.contentView**

I am objective-C person so haven't learnt swift yet.

In Objective C we check condition if cell is nil or not before instantiation.

ex.

```
if(cell == nil)
{
   # Instantiate cell here
}
```

by this cell will not instantiate for every row of indexPath.